# how to read Specific row in csv file from multiple row in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am using csv data set config to read data for data driven framework in jmeter. I have lots of data in my csv file. Suppose I want to read only data of specific row then how can i do this? I don't want to read data of all rows available in csv.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language like:

```
def line10 = new File('/path/to/your/file').readLines().get(9)
```

The above code can be called from any of [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or from [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

More information:

- [Groovy JDK enhancements](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)